# Output to log file is not coming correctly in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have an input file as shown below:

```
Date: 01-01-2007
thing1    3    7098    22394
thing2    2    6500    13000
thing3   20    300    6000
Overalltotal: 41394
-----------------------------------
Date: 04-01-2007
thing1    10    700    5000
thing2-Card    48    900    43200
Overalltotal: 46020
```

---

current output:

```
Error in calculations:
Things total for thing1 is wrong: it should be 7000 instead of 5000
Overalltotal is wrong: It should be 50200
```

Expected output:

```
Error in calculations:01-01-2007
    Things total for thing1 is wrong: it should be 21294 instead of 22394
    Overalltotal is wrong: It should be 40294
Error in calculations:04-01-2007
    Things total for thing1 is wrong: it should be 7000 instead of 5000
    Overalltotal is wrong: It should be 50200
```

Code so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

# To create new files based on each date and copy the contents till the dashed line.
awk -F' ' '{fn=$1".log";sub(/^.* /,"",fn);print>fn;close(fn)}' \
    FS='\n' OFS='\n' RS='---+\n' ORS='' $1 

for f in *.log; do  
    (awk 'NF && NR>1 && $0!~/total:/{
     r=$2*$3; v=(v!="")? v"+"r : r; 
     if(r!=$4){ things_er[$1]=r" instead of "$4 }
         err_t+=$4; t+=r; $4=r
     }
     $0~/total/ && err_t { 
     print $1,"("v")",$3,t; print "Error in calculations:" | "cat 1>&2"; 
         for(i in things_er) { print "Things total for "i" is wrong: it should be "things_er[i] | "cat 1>&2"; } 
         print "Overalltotal is wrong: It should be "t | "cat 1>&2"; next 
     }1' "$f") 2> error_log
 done
```

In my error log file I do not see first date's error in calculations, also i need to print the date in error log file. Could anyone let me know why the error in calculations for 01-01-2007 is not coming? Also, how to print date as shown in expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is overly complicated and confused. Better start again from scratch.

The following AWK command in the `for` loop prints the desired output:

```
for f in *.log; do  
  awk '
    /Date/ {
      date=$2;
    }

    NF > 2 {
      r = $2*$3;
      if(r != $4) {
        check_if_first_error();
        printf "\tThings total for %s is wrong: it should be %d instead of %d\n", $1, r, $4;
      }
      overall_total += r;
    }

    /total/ {
      if (overall_total != $2) {
        check_if_first_error();
        printf "\tOveralltotal is wrong: it should be %d instead of %d\n", overall_total, $2;
      }
    }

    function check_if_first_error() {
      if (!has_previous_error) {
        printf "Error in calculations: %s\n", date;
        has_previous_error = 1;
      }
    }
    ' "$f"
done &>error_log
```

`error_log`:

```
Error in calculations: 01-01-2007
    Things total for thing1 is wrong: it should be 21294 instead of 22394
    Overalltotal is wrong: it should be 40294 instead of 41394
Error in calculations: 04-01-2007
    Things total for thing1 is wrong: it should be 7000 instead of 5000
    Overalltotal is wrong: it should be 50200 instead of 46020
```

Comment: Well, first you have to understand how AWK works: an AWK program is a sequence of `pattern{action}` statements. Each line (or more precisely, each record, which by default is a line) is compared in sequence to each `pattern`, and if it matches the pattern, then the `{action}` is executed. So, in my answer there are three patterns, the first one matching the "date" line, the second one matching all the "thing" lines, and the third one matching the "total" line.

Comment: Functions really work just like in any other programming languages. They can be *defined* anywhere in the code, and they are not executed where they are defined, but where they are *invoked* (which is at two places in my answer). The only reason I introduced this function is to avoid the duplication of a piece of code (the code in the function body). You could rewrite the code without the function by just replacing the statement `check_if_first_error()` with the code in the function body.